# Exporting to excel export converts special characters to HTML codes

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I need to export Date, Title and Description to excel file, right now i am facing two issue with the export of excel file.

one special characters such as `',"` an other characters turn into  `&lsquo;` `&amp;` etc....

All these issue are with the Description column, which stored text in HTML format. Below is the example of text in various formats

**Actual Text**
The ‘ Golf Season Opening’ marked the official opening of the at Golf Club, Season to start on March 10, 2018.

**Text Stored in Database MS SQL SERVER**

The  ‘Golf Season Opening ‘ marked the official opening of the at Golf Club& Season to start on March 10& 2018.

**Text exported to Excel** 
The  ‘Golf Season Opening ‘ marked the official opening of the at Golf Club& Season to start on March 10& 2018.

I am using below code to create excel file but i am facing above issue.

How can i store text without being decoding text is excel should be store in text format & all special characters show properly without any issue

```
 var wb = new XLWorkbook();
 var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Calendar");

 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            var rowIndex = 2; // 1 = header row
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ws.Cell("A" + rowIndex).Value = row["Year"];
                ws.Cell("B" + rowIndex).Value = row["Title"];

                string noHTML = Regex.Replace(row["Description"].ToString(), @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
                string noHTMLNormalised = Regex.Replace(noHTML, @"\s{2,}", " ");
                ws.Cell("C" + rowIndex).Value = noHTMLNormalised;

                rowIndex++;
            }

            //// From worksheet
            var rngTable = ws.Range("A1:C" + rowIndex);

            var rngHeader = ws.Range("A1:C1");

            var rngYear = ws.Range("A2:A" + rowIndex);

            //var rngDate = ws.Range("B2:B" + rowIndex);

            var rngTitle = ws.Range("B2:D" + rowIndex);

            var rngDesc = ws.Range("C2:C" + rowIndex);

            rngHeader.Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.CoolGrey);
            rngHeader.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
            rngHeader.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            rngHeader.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

           // rngYear.Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.CoolGrey);
            rngYear.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            rngYear.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
            rngYear.Style.Alignment.Indent = 1;


            //rngDate.Style.DateFormat.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY";
            //rngDate.Style.Alignment.Indent = 10;

            rngDesc.Style.Alignment.SetWrapText();

            ws.RangeUsed().Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thick;

            var col3 = ws.Column("C");
            //col3.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
            col3.Width = 100;

            ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

            string fileName;

            fileName = "Golf_Calendat.xlsx"; 

            wb.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../excel/" + fileName));
```

Any help to fixed the above issue and also if we we can wrap the text in description column and if row can take the auto height based on the wrapped text.

Just to mention i am using `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` for excel export

Answer (score 0):

you can replace it in a string

```
str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved Both issue with following code

First by using HTML `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`
`string htmlDec = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row["Description"].ToString());`

and text wrap issue with `ws.Column(2).AdjustToContents(5, 7);`

```
        string htmlEnc = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(row["Description"].ToString());
        string htmlDec = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row["Description"].ToString());


        string noHTML = Regex.Replace(htmlDec, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim(); 

        string noHTMLNormalised = Regex.Replace(noHTML, @"\s{2,}", " ");


        ws.Cell("C" + rowIndex).Value = noHTMLNormalised;
```